# Java rename files

Tags: java

I have a list of files and I want to rename them on specific rules. I wrote this code in java, it runs but it doesn't work. It doesn't rename the files. Please help me.

```
import java.io.File;

public class ChangeName {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       File cartella=new File("D:\\LibriInformatica");
       File[] listaDiFile=cartella.listFiles();
       for (int i=0; i<listaDiFile.length;i++){
           if(listaDiFile[i].isFile()){
               String[] titolo=listaDiFile[i].toString().split("\\\\");

               String[] nomeSplit2;

               //Regole di split e rinomino
               if(titolo[2].contains("( PDFDrive )")){//rinomino il file se contiene la parola ( PDFDrive eliminandola)
                   System.out.println("Nome file originale: "+listaDiFile[i].toString());
                   String[] rinomino1= titolo[2].split("PDFDrive");
                   titolo[2]=rinomino1[0]+".pdf";
                   String nomeDefinitivo="D:\\LibriInformatica"+titolo[2];
                   listaDiFile[i].renameTo(new File(nomeDefinitivo));
                   System.out.println("Nome file cambiato: "+listaDiFile[i].toString());
               }
               if(titolo[2].contains("_")){//Rinomino eliminando _
                   String[] rinomino1= titolo[2].split("_");
                   titolo[2]=rinomino1[0]+".pdf";
                   String nomeDefinitivo="D:\\LibriInformatica"+titolo[2];
                   listaDiFile[i].renameTo(new File(nomeDefinitivo));
               }
               if(titolo[2].contains("-")){//Rinomino eliminando -
                   String[] rinomino1= titolo[2].split("-");
                   titolo[2]=rinomino1[0]+".pdf";
                   String nomeDefinitivo="D:\\LibriInformatica"+titolo[2];
                   listaDiFile[i].renameTo(new File(nomeDefinitivo));
               }
           }
       }

   }
}
```

Comment: Did you try writing code to rename one file?

Comment: Rename will return true if it works, did you check the value your getting back? Maybe add a line for debugging `if(!listaDiFile[i].renameTo(new File(nomeDefinitivo)){ System.out.println("couldn't rename " + listaDiFile + " to " + nomeDefinitivo); }` That way you can see if you're executing the right code blocks, and if the names are what you expect.

Comment: matt i have a long list of pdf file in different format of name.

Comment: Your example doesn't have enough information for somebody to help, you need to check what files your trying to move, and what the return is. That said, it doesn't make sense that you use `listaDiFile[i].toString().split("\\\\")` when you already have a File that you can manipulate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it. The file renamed must be saved in a different folder, because the system don't rename the original file. This is a momentanly solution. In the future i will search something for optimize the alghoritm

Comment: It doesn't sound like you've reached a correct conclusion. You should just be able to rename a file if you know the original name of the file and the output name. I would suggest using the newer api, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html